# The scene was set for the final showdown

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The scene was set for the final showdown.

(from a dictionary example)

What does the sentence mean? And in what context is the sentence used?

I already know the word 'showdown'.

Does the sentence mean they are shooting some scenes and the final showdown scene is ready to be shot because they finished setting the schedule and place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could, but the expression is much more likely to be metaphorical.

Everything was ready - the circumstances were just right - for the final showdown (a big argument intended to settle a dispute once and for all).